# Prevent user from entering page again after logout

Tags: php, mysql

I've created this code so that the user will not redirect onto the next page again. I set the maximum value on votenow button to 1 and once the user click the button again the value on the votenow button will not be added anymore since its maximum is 1. Everything works fine except that the user can still access the nextpage though the maximum value on the button was reached. Here's the code.

```
<?php
  $errors = array(); 
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","registration");

  if(isset($_POST['votenow']))
    {

        $votenow ="0";
        $votenow1="1";
        if($votenow != $votenow1){ 
            $votenow = "update users set votenow = votenow + 1 WHERE votenow=0 LIMIT 1 ";
            $run_vote = mysqli_query($db,$votenow);
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello!");</script>';
        header ("Refresh:2; url=renewsys3.php");
        }

        else{   
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("oh not again!");</script>';
            header ("Refresh:2; url=renewsys2re.php");
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Can you guys help me or is there any other way so that the user will not enter the next page again? Btw, this is a voting system

Comment: Do you store anything like a user_id or something similar in the sessions array when a user is logged in?

Comment: Yes. I have student number sir

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use session:

```
$_SESSION['votenow'] = 0;
if (isset($_SESSION['votenow'])) {
   if (!$_SESSION['votenow']) {
    //do something
  } else { // means $_SESSION['votenow'] == 1
  // do something else
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response sir but can you sir please elaborate it? :( I don't kinda get it :(

Comment: I gave it a try then this happens sir –  Fatal error: Cannot use temporary expression in write context in C:\Users\Xtian\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\mainsys\renewsys2re.php on line 42. I did fix the problem but the votes were not updating and not redirecting to next page.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the URL to a different page (maybe homepage or any page) If the maximum vote is reached.
Let that code run before any other code so that the page won't load of the condition is true. It'll redirect immediately.

Comment: Sad to say, but the users can still enter the next page sir. :(

Comment: Then you're not redirecting well, if it does, no one should be able to visit the page if the user vote has reach maximum. Or maybe I'm not understanding your question well.